# Best Key to use when storing GameObjects in Hashtable? - Unity, C#

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working towards writing a script to take a "snapshot" of the initial attributes of all children of a GameObject. Namely at startup I want to save the position, orientation & color of all these objects in a `Hashtable`. The user has the ability to move & modify these objects during runtime, and I want to update the Hashtable to keep track of this. This will allow me to create an **Undo last action** button.

I found that `gameObject.name` isn't a good `Key` for my `Hashtable` entries because sometimes multiple game objects have the same name (like "cube"). So what would make a better `Key`? It's clear that Unity differentiate between two identical game objects with the same name, but how? I don't want to have to manually `Tag` every game object. I want to eventually bring in a large CAD file with hundreds of parts, and automatically record them all in a Hashtable.

For example, the code below works fine, unless I have multiple game objects with the same name. Then I get this error *ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Cube'  Key being added: 'Cube'*

```
public class GetAllObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Hashtable allObjectsHT = new();
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("--Environment: GetAllObjects.cs <<<<<<<<<<");
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            allObjectsHT.Add(child.gameObject.name, child);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just use the objects themselves.

Comment: @Chuck That worked! Why didn't I think of that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Chuck this is what I want, and you solved my problem:

```
public class GetAllObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    UnityEngine.Vector3 startPosition;
    UnityEngine.Quaternion startRotation;

    public Hashtable allObjectsHT = new();
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("--Environment: GetAllObjects.cs <<<<<<<<<<");
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            startPosition = child.position;
            startRotation = child.rotation;
            Hashtable objHT = new();
            objHT.Add("position", startPosition);
            objHT.Add("rotation", startRotation);
            allObjectsHT.Add(child, objHT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey happy to help! Remember - anything can be a key!

Comment: Just looking at your code again - be careful. I'm not sure how you're planning on accessing this later, but you will need the key, and right now your key and value are the same thing, so that's not making any sense to me - If you have `child` then you don't need to look up `child`. Maybe you meant to store the `child.gameObject`? As in `allObjectsHT.Add(child.gameObject, child);`

Answer (score 1):

It's good to use meaningful keys you can refer to, otherwise you'd just use a collection without keys like a `List`. You could use an [editor script](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/editor-scripting) to name all of the objects you import and use the names as keys. e.g.

```
int i = 0;
foreach(GameObject g in Selection.gameObjects)
{
     g.name = "Object_" + i.ToString();
     i++;
}
```

You could make the naming more sophisticated and meaningful of course, this is just an example.